# Programmatically perform click on Actor libgdx

Tags: libgdx, scene2d

My question is straightforward.

I have some `ClickListener`s added to an Actor. I want to execute a click event on them programmatically.

Something like `myActor.performClick()`;

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I figured out a solution :

```
public static void performClick(Actor actor) {
    Array<EventListener> listeners = actor.getListeners();
    for(int i=0;i<listeners.size;i++)
    {
        if(listeners.get(i) instanceof ClickListener){
            ((ClickListener)listeners.get(i)).clicked(null, 0, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

This method can be called passing the actor on whom click needs to be performed

Answer (score 14):

You can also use:

```
InputEvent event1 = new InputEvent();
event1.setType(InputEvent.Type.touchDown);
button.fire(event1);

InputEvent event2 = new InputEvent();
event2.setType(InputEvent.Type.touchUp);
button.fire(event2);
```

This will also show any pressed image change which can be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

I do it like this (seems nicer to me):

```
public void triggerButtonClicked(Button button) {
    InputEvent inputEvent = Pools.obtain(InputEvent.class);
    inputEvent.reset();
    inputEvent.setButton(0);
    inputEvent.setRelatedActor(button);

    try {
        inputEvent.setType(InputEvent.Type.touchDown);
        button.fire(inputEvent);

        inputEvent.setType(InputEvent.Type.touchUp);
        button.fire(inputEvent);
    } finally {
        Pools.free(inputEvent);
    }
}
```

Comment: If there's an exception during a real touch down the touch up will still be called right? But I don't see actual use case where perfect simulation is needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to simulate user clicking on a visible actor, then you can find a point inside actor and tell InputProcessor to send touch events there.

```
// a point in the middle of the actor
val middle = actor.localToScreenCoordinates(Vector2(
    this.width / 2,
    this.height / 2
))

// simulate left mouse button press and release
Gdx.input.inputProcessor.touchDown(
    middle.x.toInt(), 
    middle.y.toInt(), 
    0,
    Input.Buttons.LEFT
)
Gdx.input.inputProcessor.touchUp(
    middle.x.toInt(),
    middle.y.toInt(),
    0,
    Input.Buttons.LEFT
)
```

Depending on actor style, touch down event can issue a change in actor's appearance which require being on the LibGDX's main thread. So if you are not on that thread (for example, simulating a click from a JUnit test case) then `Gdx.input.inputProcessor.touchDown` and `touchUp` have to be inside `Gdx.app.postRunnable` block.