# how to do Junit test for a Libgdx class has pictures and pictures button

Tags: java, libgdx, mockito, textures, junit5

the Menu Class

```
package com.gdx.game.screens;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Screen;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.gdx.game.HuntersGame;

public class InfoScreen implements Screen {
    
    HuntersGame game;
    Texture background,backBefore,backAfter,textInfo;
    /**
     * Constructor, Links the Game instance
     * @param game the Game instance provided by the GameScreen, contains the sprite batch
     *             which is essential for rendering
     */
    public InfoScreen(HuntersGame game){
        this.game = game;
        //play button as image
        backBefore = new Texture("backBefore.png");
        backAfter = new Texture("backAfter.png");
        //text
        textInfo = new Texture("info.png");
        //background
        background = new Texture("grass-info.jpg");
    }

    @Override
    public void show() {
        
    }

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 0, 0, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        //positions of back button
        int xb= backBefore.getWidth();
        int yb= backBefore.getHeight();
        //positions of the mouse
        int x=Gdx.input.getX(),y=Gdx.input.getY();

        //start batch
        game.batch.begin();
        game.batch.draw(background,0,0,Gdx.graphics.getWidth(),Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
        game.batch.draw(textInfo,0,-30,Gdx.graphics.getWidth(),Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
        //start script for touch and click by mouse

        if(x>=0 && x<=backBefore.getWidth() && y>=0 && y<=backBefore.getHeight()){
            game.batch.draw(backAfter,0,Gdx.graphics.getHeight()-backBefore.getHeight());
            if(Gdx.input.isTouched()){
                this.dispose();
                game.setScreen(new MenuScreen(game));
            }
        }else{
            game.batch.draw(backBefore,0,Gdx.graphics.getHeight()-backBefore.getHeight());
        }

        game.batch.end();
    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {

    }

    @Override
    public void pause() {

    }

    @Override
    public void resume() {

    }

    @Override
    public void hide() {

    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {

    }
}
```

I wanted to do a test for this class I don't know how and I tried to import Mockito as every other code did but not work with me I tried for like 6 hours with no result cause I don't know how that Mockito works and search too much with no benefits and I want just an example for that class then I will try to do advanced examples
thank you in advance
PS: for the images i used you can use any image to check the code and for HunterGame class is down

```
package com.gdx.game;


import com.badlogic.gdx.Game;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.ShapeRenderer;
import com.gdx.game.screens.GameScreen;
import com.gdx.game.screens.MenuScreen;


public class HuntersGame extends Game {
    public SpriteBatch batch;

    @Override
    public void create () {
        batch = new SpriteBatch();
        this.setScreen(new MenuScreen((this)));
    }
    
    @Override
    public void dispose () {
        batch.dispose();
    }
}
[the info class looks like][1]
```

Comment: Using Mockito you can create simple dummy implementations (and many others) for parts of your tested code. But what do you want to test in the Unit-Test? If you just want to click the button [this question / answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25870645/programmatically-perform-click-on-actor-libgdx) might be helpfull.

Comment: mockito doesn't work for me, i tried many ways to install it but no progress i will see that buttons click it may help i guess even my buttons are images and the click happens with that method (Gdx.input.isTouched())